# Navigation with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm looking for an explanation of how navigation works within CI.

Basically, I have a top nav with some links and want to connect to them. I have only ever done this with

```
<a href="somelink.html">Some Link</a>
```

I understand you pass the controller then function in the href portion of the a tag, but mine does not seem to be working so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Take my products page as an example.

```
<a href ="user/products">Products</a>
```

Then the function for it in the "user" controller

```
    public function products() {

    $data['title']='Products';
    $this->load->view ('header_view', $data);
    $this->load->view ('products.php', $data);
    $this->load->view ('footer_view', $data);
}
```

The result is "Object not found on server" error message.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `<a href ="/user/products">Products</a>` - Also you might not have removed `/index.php/` from your url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't [removed `index.php` from your URL](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html), then you'll need to include it in the relative links.

The easiest way to generate a link to a controller/function is probably to use CodeIgniter's [URL Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

- The `site_url()` function will return your site's URL as specified in your config, along with whatever your *index page* and *url suffix* are, also as set in your config. If you want to create a the URL to your *products* function in your *user* controller then:

  ```
  <a href ="<?php echo site_url("user/products"); ?>">Products</a>
  ```
- You can also use the `anchor()` function. (Also in CodeIgniter's URL helper.)

  ```
  echo anchor('user/products', 'Products');
  ```

Using these functions is useful because if your site's URL was to change, you'd only need to change it **once** in your *config*, as these functions will ensure that your links will reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller name is **user**?

**user/products** normally mean  **controller_name/function** without custom routing

Your controller file

```
class User extends CI_Controll
{
        function products()
        {
            // codes
        }


}
```

In your header file to route to **products(function)**. Views/header.php

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('user/prouducts') ?>">View Products</a>
```

and will work on every pages